# Network manager dies if my router drops the internet connection

Tags: kubuntu, network-manager, internet, kde4

My ISP doing some repairs on my broadband cable so my internet connection is dropping frequently, when my internet connection drops, Network Manager, shows that there are no interfaces.
I have to restart network-manager using start and stop connections to get it working again.

Using Ubuntu with KDE 4

Comment: network manager has a dbus API and python has a dbus connector.  seems like it's time for a script

Comment: @aking1012 Hmm a python script to restart network-manager ?

Comment: Yep.  Monitor nm through a dbus connection and if you can't get out restart the service.  Simple enough, but kind of a patchwork solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of network manager fixes the issue